# How do I enable auto-complete globally on my init file?

Tags: auto-complete-mode

At some moment in time, auto-complete just stopped working for me. I added this code in my init file:

```
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

But I get this error when starting Emacs:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: global-auto-complete-mode
```

I can enable auto-complete on a per buffer basis, so I know it's installed and working. But I want it to be enabled globally by default.

Comment: Put `(require 'auto-complete)` before `(global-auto-complete-mode t)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function isn't defined at startup, that probably means the file containing the function hasn't been loaded yet. The function `global-auto-complete-mode` is in the file `auto-complete.el`, which you can see with `C-h f`, so the first thing to try is to execute

```
(require 'auto-complete)
```

before calling the function.

Comment: Duh, that was it of course. Thanks!

Comment: If you install `auto-complete` from a package, that function will be autoloaded, so you won't need to explicitly `require` the library.